# Awfully slow execution on a small datasets – where to start debugging?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-mllib

I do some experimentation on a MacBook (i5, 2.6GHz, 8GB ram) with Zeppelin NB and Spark in standalone mode. spark.executor/driver.memory both get 2g. I have also set `spark.serializer     org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer` in spark-defaults.conf, but that seems to be ignored by zeppelin

---

#### ALS model

I have trained a ALS model with ~400k (implicit) ratings and want to get recommendations with `val allRecommendations = model.recommendProductsForUsers(1)`

#### Sample set

Next I take a sample to play around with

```
val sampledRecommendations = allRecommendations.sample(false, 0.05, 1234567).cache
```

This contains 3600 recommendations.

#### Remove product recommendations that users own

Next I want to remove all ratings for products that a given user already owns, the list I hold in a RDD of the form (user_id, Set[product_ids]): `RDD[(Long, scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int])]`

```
val productRecommendations = (sampledRecommendations
// add user portfolio to the list, but convert the key from Long to Int first
.join(usersProductsFlat.map( up => (up._1.toInt, up._2) ))
.mapValues(
    // (user, (ratings: Array[Rating], usersOwnedProducts: HashSet[Long]))
    r => (r._1
        .filter( rating => !r._2.contains(rating.product))
        .filter( rating => rating.rating > 0.5)
        .toList
    )
  )
  // In case there is no recommendation (left), remove the entry
  .filter(rating => !rating._2.isEmpty)
).cache
```

**Question 1**
Calling this (`productRecommendations.count`) on the cached sample set generates a stage that includes `flatMap at MatrixFactorizationModel.scala:278` with **10,000** tasks, 263.6 MB of input data and 196.0 MB shuffle write. Shouldn't the tiny and cached RDD be used instead and what is going (wr)on(g) here? The execution of the count takes almost 5 minutes!

**Question 2**
Calling `usersProductsFlat.count` which is fully cached according to the "Storage" view in the application UI takes **~60 seconds each time**. It's 23Mb in size – shouldn't that be a lot faster?

#### Map to readable form

Next I bring this in some readable form replacing IDs with names from a broadcasted lookup Map to put into a DF/table:

```
val readableRatings = (productRecommendations
    .flatMapValues(x=>x)
    .map( r => (r._1, userIdToMailBC.value(r._1), r._2.product.toInt, productIdToNameBC.value(r._2.product), r._2.rating))
).cache
val readableRatingsDF = readableRatings.toDF("user","email", "product_id", "product", "rating").cache
readableRatingsDF.registerTempTable("recommendations")
```

#### Select … with patience

**The insane part starts here**. Doing a SELECT takes **several hours** (I could never wait for one to finish):

```
%sql
SELECT COUNT(user) AS usr_cnt, product, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM recommendations
GROUP BY product
```

[image: Query takes virtually forever]

---

I don't know where to look to find the bottlenecks here, there is obviously some huge kerfuffle going on here! Where can I start looking?

Comment: Regarding question 1 RDDs are lazily evaluated so until you execute an action (here `count`) `cache` is only a promise. Regarding question 2 - how many partitions do you have in the input dataset?.

Comment: Re the actions, that's understood. I would expect it to hit the cache with the 2nd action though. The input set I `coalesce()` to 4 partitions. But I map it to a `RDD[Rating]` later which is "fast enough" when I execute the DAG with eg. a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number of partitions may be too large. I think you should use about 200 when running in local mode rather than 10000. You can set the number of partitions in different ways. I suggest you edit the spark.default.parallelism flag in the Spark configuration file.

Comment: I don't actually parallelize anywhere. I load the raw data from a parquet file, map to Ratings(), feed the model and save it via `MatrixFactorizationModel.save(sc, path)`. The saved model data however has lots of partitions! I am trying to save with fewer data to see how this changes things. Why there must be 10,000 tasks and how to avoid this (if this makes sense at all) I don't know.

Comment: Even feeding the model with only 10k ratings takes > 15min – I did not care to wait, sth. is pretty wrong here.

Comment: In Spark, RDD's are always paralellized. See my updated answer.

Comment: When looking at how the [model is saved](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.scala#L362) there is no re-partitioning. Doc says the default is "the largest number of partitions in a parent RDD" which are the user features. I have 31 products and 73k users. So I'll try to set `spark.default.parallelism` which then should help!

Comment: Setting `spark.default.parallelism` has helped a lot and I can actually work on a  full data set! Speed is still not where I'd want it: The query takes 6 minutes to complete, training and `recommendProductsForUsers()` each ~30 minutes. Tried the same on a Databricks trial account where things run around 10times faster with 8 workers, so per worker roughly the same speed. That's just how long it takes I guess!